# Perforce streams to Git migration with all history

Tags: git, github, version-control, perforce, git-p4

I am trying to migrate from Perforce to Git. There are several blogs available for moving Perforce depot but not about migrating perforce streams and that too with all the history and relation between other streams as well. 
I have one main stream and a lot of children streams which are either development, release or task streams. I want to move everything to git with their history and stream relation and also I don't want to use perforce once everything is moved so I don't want to use tools like Helix4Git.

Can someone give me a walkthrough of how to do it? Thanks

I have already tried git-p4 but I found it the hard way that git-p4 doesn't work successfully with streams.

Whole data should be moved to git, no perforce needed after that.

Comment: If Helix4Git gives you a git repo with the structure you want, then you could use that; take the git repo and push that to github/whatever git store you are using.